# Decrease height of div that is off-screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose I have the following html/css

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B" style="height:50px">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="D">
    ...
</div>
```

What I want to do is: When the user scrolls far enough so that div `B` is off the screen (not visible), change the height of `B` to `0px`.  Essentially this means that when `D` is at the top of the screen, the following jQuery will run:

```
function changeBHeight() {
    $('.B').css("height","0px");
}
```

The only problem is, when this happens, the page is now shorter, so the browser rapidly scrolls down the page by 50px.  How can I stop this?

The user should not realize that B has collapsed unless they scroll back up to the top of the page.

Comment: Can you give a jsfiddle of what you currently have?

Comment: Try to increase the `div` with class `A`'s height so that its height won't change. Thus, only A's child will collapse but A will remain with the same height.

Comment: If the user already scrolled the element is out of sight, what is the purpose of hiding something that isn't visible to the viewport?

Comment: unusual concept...what is use case?

Comment: When you change the size of div B then the whole page size will also be affected and hence there would be scroller

Comment: Can you provide any link for that. So that We can check